# How to use partition inside partition(multilevel partition or partition of partitions) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

How to use partition inside partition in PostgreSQL
I want to do multilevel partition in PostgreSQL
Like in first table on column id and in 2nd partitioned table with column date
so that will be three level hierarchy

Comment: Huh? I don't understand.

Comment: this is very simple

Comment: you can check this article heading and my question heading include same content
https://joaodlf.com/postgresql-10-partitions-of-partitions.html

Comment: There is an example in the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-EXAMPLE

Comment: thanks. I will read it as well to boost my skills and experties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is explained well in this article with examples
https://joaodlf.com/postgresql-10-partitions-of-partitions.html

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals (
    dt_total date NOT NULL,
    geo varchar(2) not null,
    impressions integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    sales integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt_total);
```

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_201801
PARTITION OF dt_totals
FOR VALUES FROM ('2018-01-01') TO ('2018-01-31');
```

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_201801
PARTITION OF dt_totals
FOR VALUES FROM ('2018-01-01') TO ('2018-01-31')
PARTITION BY LIST (geo);
```

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_UK_201801 PARTITION OF dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('UK');
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_US_201801 PARTITION OF dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('US');
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_AU_201801 PARTITION OF dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('AU');
```